# Objects not deleting

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have several ViewSets.They have one serializer and model.
For example - ViewSet "Posts" and "Favorites". If I use DELETE request on Post object, he is deleted from "Posts", but in Favorites, I can see them. BUT, every object has a "URL" field. So, if some object from "Posts" will be deleted, then in "Favorites" I will see it and if I go to the link from the "URL" field, then I get "404 not found".

Why does it happen?

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name='city', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name='description', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    isFan = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
    first_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
    second_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
```

ViewSets:

```
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.is_actual().order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = (...)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)


class ClosedPostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.is_not_actual().order_by('-end_time')

    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = (...)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)


class SearchViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Post.objects.is_actual()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = (...)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        result_list = list(queryset.values('city').annotate(count=Count('city')))
        return Response(result_list)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Exactly what are the favorites here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, hi! It was just an example. This case useful in these viewsets and models.